# C++/CLI Tuple is not a member of System

Tags: c++-cli, tuples

I'm getting a compilation error (no IntelliSense errors though) when I use System::Tuple in .NET v4.0.

**Code:** `System::Tuple<int, int, int>^ tuple1 = gcnew System::Tuple<int, int, int>(1, 1, 1);`

**Error text:** `error C2039: 'Tuple' : is not a member of 'System'`

I've used Tuple in C# without such issues, is something different about C++/CLI?

Comment: I just checked some code of mine, and other than having a `using namespace System;` and `gcnew Tuple<...`, looks ok to me.

Comment: I thought it might be a missing reference to another assembly that has the System namespace (System.Core or something like that), but http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387150%28v=vs.100%29.aspx says it's in mscorlib.dll.

Comment: Yes, I checked and included #using for System, System.Core and mscorelib.dll. No difference. I can see in the object browser Tuple class is available, just can't be used for some strange reasons.